# Как закруглить края кнопки tkinter на Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

Я пытался найти это в гугле, но безрезультатно. Пожалуйста, подскажите, как можно закруглить края кнопки, созданной с помощью модуля tkinter на Python?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42579927/rounded-button-tkinter-python/45536589

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нарисуйте округлую кнопку ( `rounded_button.png` ), и используйте так:

```
...
self.loadimage = tk.PhotoImage(file="rounded_button.png")
self.roundedbutton = tk.Button(self, image=self.loadimage)
self.roundedbutton["bg"] = "white"
self.roundedbutton["border"] = "0"
self.roundedbutton.pack(side="top")
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы сделать закругленную кнопку в tkinter нужно нарисовать кнопку в графическом редакторе и задать ее как картинку для кнопки

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button
from PIL import ImageTk  # $ pip install pillow

root = Tk()
roundButton = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="image.png")
Button(root, border=0, image=image, command=function()).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: По сути та же самая идея, что в соседнем ответе, только еще PIL используется.

Comment: Да, но кому как удобнее. Мой код покороче.

Comment: В обоих вариантах значимые 2 строки, нет смысла меряться тут длиной кода.